Compactification of M theory on $Spin(7)$ manifolds
In their book (chapter 9, page 438-439), the authors K. Becker, M. Becker and J. H. Schwarz discussed about $Spin(7)$ compactifications of M theory. Since the $Spin(7)$ manifolds are eight dimensional, the effective theory obtained from the compactification is three dimensional with $\mathcal{N} =1$ supersymmetry. Then they mentioned that Witten had speculated that there is a four-dimensional quantum field theory that, when compactified on a circle, becomes this $\mathcal{N}=1$ theory in three dimensions. But they didn't mention any reference to that. Are there any literature/papers on this?

I suppose Ed was refering to the compactification of 11d supergravity on $G_2$-manifolds. nLab has some of the details and references.
